# lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _FSEventStreamCreate

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, fs

has anyone recently faced issues with create-react-app and npm start? I'm running on mac, node-14.5 and xcode is updated.

Here's the error message:
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _FSEventStreamCreate

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should have been fixed by recent version updates to React. However, if you still face the same issue and need a quick fix, simply remove `fsevents` folder from your `node_modules`. Cheers! (: